# Why is it the sum of even numbers are higher than sum of odd numbers?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

I was just wondering I solve the first 50 even numbers so it's $(50)(51)$ $=$ $2550$ while 50 first odd is $n^2$ so $2500$. In numbers 1-10 there are 5 odds and 5 evens so why are they not equal?

Answer (score 4):

Every odd contributes one less than the even following it.  So for example,
$$2 + 4 + 6 + 8 + 10 = (1+1) + (3+1) + (5+1) + (7+1) + (9+1) = 1 + 3 + 5 + 7 + 9 + (1+1+1+1+1)$$
so as you can see the sum of the first 5 evens is 5 higher than the sum of the first 5 odds.

Answer (score 4):

The $n$th [positive] even number is always one greater than the $n$th [positive] odd number. For example: $1$ is the first odd number, $2$ is the first even number, and $2 > 1$.

Answer (score 4):

You can pair up the odds and evens.  Each even is one greater than the corresponding odd, so the sum is greater by the number of numbers in your sum. If you started the evens from $0$ instead of $2$, they would be one less than all the odds and the sum of the first $50$ evens would be $(49)(50)=2450$